# Display validation error within a popup window (modal)

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I want to display the form validation error within the Modal, but the errors are being displayed in a new page

> View

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="modelError">hi</div>
                <?php echo form_open('welcome/add_data','id="myform"'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="user_name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">User Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Save</button>
            </div>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Ajax

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('submit','#myform',function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            let name=$("#name").val();
            let user_name=$("#user_name").val();
             $.ajax({
                    url:"<?php echo base_url(). 'welcome/add_data';?>",
                    method: 'POST',
                    data:new FormData(this),
                    contentType:false,
                    processData:false,
                    success: function(data) {
                     var myObj = JSON.parse(data);
                     var msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">'+myObj.error+'</div>';
                     $('#modelError').html(msg);
                     },
                    error: function() {
                     alert('Error get data from ajax');
                    }
                }
            });
        })
    })
</script>
```

> Controller

```
public function add_data(){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->msg['error'] = validation_errors();
            echo json_encode($this->msg);
        }

        else {
            $data=array(
                'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
                'user_name'=>$this->input->post('user_name'),
            );
            $this->Test_model->add_data($data);
            redirect('welcome',"refresh");
        }

    }
```

I expect the errors within the Modal (pop up window), but the errors are displayed in a new page "localhost/ajax/welcome/add_data"

I have tried lots of code snippets from stackoverflow but none of them works.

Comment: If that's the case so i think the form is being normally submitted then redirected .. your ajax didn't work .. make sure by alerting right after the opening of ajax call!

Comment: why do you have a redirect function in an ajax controller? ajax expects a response, usually in json format. you are essentially sending the ajax request to a new page when there is a success. also i don't see any reason why your code is sending you to a new page. try to console log the result and see what happens.

Comment: @SherifSalah No the modal works fine while submitting valid input, only when I submit blank input the view page disappears and the error "username field is required" is displayed on a new page

Comment: That's not my question, make sure your ajax is working and the form is not submitting normally.